# What are CSS @ Blocks?

Tags: css, visual-studio

In the CSS Outline, Visual Studio has a folder titled, "@ Blocks" .  What is it talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@ Blocks` is where Visual Studio will outline any `@` statements. THe `@` provide ability to add apply a set of rules to a specific declaration. They are also used for `@import` which allows you to nest CSS files. They are also used to define media type, for example `@media print` can set styles for when the page is printed. Here is the W3C definition: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#x6

Answer (score 2):

From W3...

> Media Types allow you to specify how
>   documents will be presented in
>   different media. The document can be
>   displayed differently on the screen,
>   on the paper, with an aural browser,
>   etc.

http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_mediatypes.asp

so, this will show up in the "@ Blocks" section

```
@media print   
{  
    p.test {font-family:times,serif;font-size:10px;}
}
```

Comment: Correct, but it is more than just media types.